# .net photo select 'wand' functionality

Tags: .net, photos

Is there any way using .net I can emulate the wand functionality found in your normal photo editor?
I.e. user clicks on part of a photo and the application automatically selects the surrounding X pixels based on a given factor (usually tolerance threshold).

Any idea on how I could do this with .net?
Thanks

Comment: This question is MUCH too broad I think.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do basic pixel manipulation to accomplish this.  I would start by storing the color of the pixel they clicked, then instantiate a 2D array of ints that is the same dimensions as the image.  Change the int that corresponds to the pixel they clicked on to a 1.  At that point, you just have to use a pseudo-mapping algorithm to explode outwards, changing matching pixels to "1" in your array, and nonmatching pixels to "-1".

Eventually you'll have a minesweeper-esque 2D array with a heart of 1s, and edges of -1s, and then the uncheckable areas still at 0.  The 1s then become the selected area

Answer (score 0):

You want to do a [flood fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) using your tolerance threshold criteria to determine if a pixel should be included or not.

The details are a bit too much for a simple StackOverflow answer. As you can see from the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill), there are many nuances just to the flood fill algorithm.